# Angularjs input fields empty or not validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WMUJzr1Tlgp0NIVjNTkT?p=preview)

```
<ul ng-repeat="fields in data">
<li>
  <input type="text" ng-model="fields.field2.i">
</li>

<li>
  <input type="text" ng-model="fields.field2.ii">
</li>

<li>
  <input type="text" ng-model="fields.field2.iii">
</li>
</ul>
```

How to check all the fields is filled or not in angularjs? Check the ng-model or the json's object?

Answer (score 2):

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LMcEZ7cES8rnh0SyQeBM?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
   <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <form name="form">
      <ul ng-repeat="fields in data">
         <li>
            <input type="text" ng-model="fields.field2.i" required>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="text" ng-model="fields.field2.ii" required>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="text" ng-model="fields.field2.iii" required>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, you should use 'required' on all the required fields and only allow the click on the save button if all fields are fulfilled. This is the very basic form of validation, for more information see this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)